# zfs on linux compression and dedup order

Tags: linux, compression, zfs, deduplication

What is the order for data written to a zfs filesystem on zfs on linux?

The only specific document i found at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36835/gkknx.html says; `When a file is written, the data is compressed, encrypted, and the checksum is verified. Then, the data is deduplicated, if possible.`

but if that was true then dedup would not dedup blocks compressed with different compression algorithms.

I tested mysqlf and i believe that the order is the following: `dedup, compress, encrypt`.

My test-Setting:

```
zpool create tank /dev/sdb
zfs create tank/lz4
zfs create tank/gzip9
zfs set compression=lz4 tank/lz4
zfs set compression=gzip-9 tank/gzip9
zfs set dedup=on tank
```

Output of `zfs list`

```
NAME         USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
tank         106K  19,3G    19K  /tank
tank/gzip9    19K  19,3G    19K  /tank/gzip9
tank/lz4      19K  19,3G    19K  /tank/lz4
```

generate a random file with `dd if=/dev/urandom of=random.txt count=128K bs=1024`

```
131072+0 Datensätze ein
131072+0 Datensätze aus
134217728 Bytes (134 MB) kopiert, 12,8786 s, 10,4 MB/s
```

Output of zpool list on empty pool:

```
NAME   SIZE  ALLOC   FREE  EXPANDSZ   FRAG    CAP  DEDUP  HEALTH  ALTROOT
tank  19,9G   134K  19,9G         -     0%     0%  1.00x  ONLINE  -
```

Then copy the files to the datasets with different compression algos:

```
 cp random.txt /tank/lz4
 cp random.txt /tank/gzip9
```

Output of `zfs list` after copying:

```
NAME         USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
tank         257M  19,1G    19K  /tank
tank/gzip9   128M  19,1G   128M  /tank/gzip9
tank/lz4     128M  19,1G   128M  /tank/lz4
```

Output of `zpool list` afer copying:

```
NAME   SIZE  ALLOC   FREE  EXPANDSZ   FRAG    CAP  DEDUP  HEALTH  ALTROOT
tank  19,9G   129M  19,7G         -     0%     0%  2.00x  ONLINE  -
```

The dedup-ratio is **2.0** after copying the same file to different datasets. In my opinion this means that dedup is done on **data**-blocks before compression and encryption.

Please could someone verify if this is correct?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turns out, that http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36835/gkknx.html is right.

> When a file is written, the data is compressed, encrypted, and the checksum is verified. Then, the data is deduplicated, if possible.

My assumption with the random file was incorrect. It seems that ZFS aborts compression if it cannot achieve a certain minimum compression ratio.

quote from https://wiki.illumos.org/display/illumos/LZ4+Compression

> Another particular thing to note is that LZ4's performance on incompressible data is very high. It achieves this by incorporating an "early abort" mechanism which will trigger if LZ4 can't meet the expected minimum compression ratio (12.5% on ZFS).

For testing i created a textfile from my filesystem with `find / >> tree.txt`.

After copying the file to both datasets and then `zpool get dedupratio` did return:

```
NAME  PROPERTY    VALUE  SOURCE
tank  dedupratio  1.00x  -
```

**Dedup is really the last part in this write chain. Choosing different compression-algorithms will result in poor dedupratio!**

Unfortunately my ZoL-version does not support encryption. But it seems that encrypting different datasets could also ruin dedup. Info on encryption: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E53394_01/html/E54801/gkkih.html